# Textbook derivation of relativistic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, textbook-erratum

I am working through this textbook derivation, and I don't quite understand how this step is justified.
I have a link to the page below but briefly the step I don't understand is the jump from $$K= \int m\frac{d}{dt}(γu) dx$$ To...
$$K= \int m\frac{d(γu)}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}$$ How is it possible to rearrange a derivative like this?

Here is the link:
(https://phys.libretexts.org/Courses/Muhlenberg_College/MC%3A_Physics_121_-_General_Physics_I/05%3A__Relativity/5.10%3A_Relativistic_Energy)

Comment: you have a typo in the 2nd equation, it is missing a "$dt$"

Comment: @hyportnex:  It's missing in the LibreText link as well.

Comment: It is almost as if they did not proof-read their own work, get someone to check it, or use it to teach anyone.  Consider yourself a beta-tester!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone pointed out, the original source has a mistake.  It should be

$$K= \int m\frac{d(γu)}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}\color{red}{dt}$$

This is via the chain rule:

$$dx=\frac{dx}{dt}dt$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This was my first time asking a question here and I’m glad it actually go answered!